# Create new shapes by merging an existing shape

Tags: qgis, sql, merge, spatial-database, mergeshapes

I want to create a new shapefile from an existing one.

I would like to create a new shapefile for next level of geo hierarchy (say regions) by grouping some of features (states) from the existing shapefile.

I have a CSV file which contains the geo hierarchy relationship (i.e., which all states to be combined to form a region).

1. Imported the CSV file as a text delimited layer
2. Joined it with the existing shapefile
3. Using "Select Features using Expression" I am able to select all the sales which forms the particular region
4. Then I went to Edit-->Merge Selected features to merge the selected featues (states) to form the region

Doing so I was able to create one region but since I want to create 100 regions by joining several states, is there not an automated way like using some SQL, etc., wherein I can create a group by query to group various states (features)? And also one region could overlap with another i.e. one state can belong to two-three regions, is it possible to have a overlapping shares layered over each other?

Comment: Perhaps Vector-Geoprocessing tools-Dissolve. QGIS has also quite good documentation http://qgis.org/en/docs/index.html.

Comment: It would certainly be easily possible to any of the things you ask in SQL, if the data were in a database. Since the data is in an ASCII file and a shapefile,  you may be limited in what you can accomplish.  The Dissolve operator is frequently used to union neighboring geometries, but each can only be allocated to one shape. This question violates the "One question per Question" policy here at GIS SE; I recommend you edit it to focus the one issue most pressing to you (and if it's a multi-allocating Dissolve, you should focus on that much sooner than the last sentence).